# Set operators not provided by Data.Vector of Haskell, what is the reason

Tags: haskell, vector, set, operations

My application involves heavy array operations (e.g. `log(1)` indexing), thus [Data.Vector](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector.html) and [Data.Vector.Unboxed](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/vector/0.9.1/doc/html/Data-Vector-Unboxed.html) are preferred to [Data.List](http://www.haskell.org/ghc/docs/latest/html/libraries/base/Data-List.html). 
It also involves many set operations (e.g. intersectBy), which however, are not provided by the Data.Vector.

Each of these functions can be implemented like in Data.List in 3-4 lines . 
Is there any reason they all not implemented with Data.Vector? I can only speculate. Maybe set operations in Data.Vector is discouraged for performance reasons, i.e. intersectBy would first produce the intersection through list comprehension and then convert the list into a Data.Vector?

Comment: Have you considered using [`Data.Set`](http://hackage.haskell.org/packages/archive/containers/latest/doc/html/Data-Set.html)?

Comment: @MikhailGlushenkov, yes, I think `Data.Set` and `Data.HashSet` both would work.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I assume it's missing because intersection of unsorted, immutable arrays must have a worst-case run time of `Ω(n*m)` without using additional space and `Data.Vector` is optimized for performance. If you want, you can write that function yourself, though:

```
import Data.Vector as V

intersect :: Eq a => V.Vector a -> V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
intersect x = V.filter (`V.elem` x)
```

Or by using [a temporary set data structure](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/unordered-containers) to achieve an expected `O(n + m)` complexity:

```
import Data.HashSet as HS

intersect :: (Hashable a, Eq a) => V.Vector a -> V.Vector a -> V.Vector a
intersect x = V.filter (`HS.member` set)
    where set = HS.fromList $ V.toList x
```

If you can afford the extra memory usage, maybe you can use some kind of aggregate type for your data, for example an array for fast random access and a hash trie like `Data.HashSet` for fast membership checks and always keep both containers up to date. That way you can reduce the asymptotic complexity for intersection to something like `O(min(n, m))`

Comment: I believe the computation cost of `HS.fromList` is `O(n)` which is not a concern compare to the brute force `O(n*m)`. I am intending to implement intersectBy and I will see how the HashSet or HashMap idea applies.

Comment: But still, I feel `Data.Vector` could have provided these operators.

Comment: `fromList` should be about O(n log(n)), since it uses the O(log(n)) `insert` function n times internally.

Comment: @ChaiT.Rex  You are right, it's a hash trie not a classic hash table. Construction should still be possible in O(n*W) in theory, but is implemented using repeated insertion as you suggested